# Multiply without multiplying, without loops either

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Make a function, method, program or routine that will accept two interger parameters (say `x` and `y`) and the total of the two values multiplied. Except straight multiplication is not allowed so you must not simply do something like:

```
int multiply (int x, int y) {
    return x*y;
}
```

Also you must not use a `for ()` loop, like this:

```
int multiply (int x, int y) {
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < y; i++){
        z += x;
    }
    return z;
}
```

Everything else is up to you. A winner is you with the most compact solution.

Comment: What about division?

Comment: Do X without Y is generally considered a bad idea for a challenge.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but this may be a duplicate. Example functions/methods are for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: "What about division?"... from above "Everything else is up to you" so what about division?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers ATaco is referring to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/8478).

Comment: Can said integers be negative?

Comment: You say "two integer parameters", but from your second code snippet it seems you mean "_positive_ integers". Can you clarify?

Comment: The function examples are for illustrative purposes only; +/- numbers are allowed

Comment: When I say "numbers" I mean integers.

Comment: But then the second snippet would produce a wrong result for negative inputs. So it's not really illustrative

Comment: Yes it's for illustrative purposes only, as in it's an example.

Comment: Again, it's a _misleading_ example, as it produces _wrong_ results. I think it should be deleted, or modified to account for the sign

Comment: Okay well I think it's going to be closed anyway (I noticed a potential duplicate after the fact, by which time someone had posted an answer). Sorry for the confusion, but my point was not to use `for()` loops, regardless of what C script was contained in the `for()` loop.

Comment: I think this is closeable both as too broad, and as unclear. (Is `*` in Underload a valid answer, for example? It *concatenates* its two arguments, but Underload uses a representation for integers in which concatenating them causes them to be multiplied, sort of like *xy* in mathematics means *x* × *y*.)

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Why not ban other loops such as `while(){}` or `do{}while()`? `while(){}` can be made to work as a *repeat **n** times* loop too.

Comment: This is very likely to be closed so I wouldn't worry about it. Anyway I would have had to give an example of every type of loop and in every language I could think of, including -/+ counts.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers First of all, this challenge has been already closed. Second, I think that +/- support can be easily added using absolute values.

Comment: If "Put on hold" means the same as "closed" then you are right. So why ask questions on something that has been closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ruby, 27 bytes

```
->i,j{(j!=0)?(i/(1.0/j)):0}
```

Comment: What about `j=0`?

Comment: @Sanchises fixed

Comment: Yes I can see division by zero being an issue unless Ruby returns `infinity` as an answer

Comment: j=0 is no problem, at least on ruby 2.3. Just try it.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
Exp@*Tr@*Log
```

Pure function taking a list of numbers (even complex numbers) as input and returning a number. Takes the logarithm of all the numbers in the list, adds them together, and exponentiates the result. Rules of exponents and logarithms ftw! (And because Mathematica calculates `Log[0]` as `-∞` and can subsequently manipulate that symbolically, it arrives at the correct answer if one input number equals `0`.)

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Tr[1^Flatten@Array[,#]]&
```

Pure function taking a list of nonnegative (unfortunately) integers as input and returning their product. Simply creates an array of the appropriate dimensions and counts the number of entries (using `Tr[1^...]` as a golfy shorthand for `Length@...`). Since we don't care what's actually in the array, we can fill it with `Null`s using `Array[,#]`, which doesn't cost any bytes for the first argument.

Comment: But how can you compute exponents and logarithms without using multiplication internally? (That's the issue with this sort of challenge -- the rules need to be specified in detail.)

Comment: Quite a good point. Mathematica doesn't actually compute the decimal expansion of say `Log[2]` unless you make it; it just knows how `Log` and `Exp` interact with each other. But of course, a transformation rule like `Exp[Log[a]+Log[b]] = a*b` uses multiplication behind the scenes. (The OP says "straight multiplication" isn't allowed, so presumably this is? But yeah, I agree with your issue.)

Comment: I think this follows the OP's rules -- you don't literally use multiplication in your program. I just think that the challenge could be worded in a way that would make it more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>48</s> 39 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to @ovs

```
f=lambda x,y,t=0:x and f(x-1,y,t+y)or t
```

Recursively adds `y` to `t`, and returns the sum of `t` when x is 0.

Comment: `lambda a,b:eval(("+a"*b)[1:])` would work. This won't work when `b` is 0 though.

Comment: Would that not also count as "straight multiplication"?

Comment: I don't know :/ Might as well be.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 22 bytes

```
->a,b{eval ?a<<42<<98}
```

Maybe bending the rules? This is no "straight" multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

18 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/.*/"$&+"x<>.0/ee
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#U1YsSC3KUdAt@F@sr6elr6Sipq1UYWOnZ6Cfmvr/vymXGQA)

It takes two numbers (say `m` and `n`) and converts them into `m+m+...+m+0` (n times) and evaluates this string. (the final `+0` is to make sure that if one of the number is `0`, then the result is `0` and not an empty string)